# How to return a relation with a row in the same table

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

**My Table structure**

Users table

- id
- parent_id

**How i want the system to work**

This db users table is set up for a school system that has multiple user types (student, parent and teacher)

A student has a parent_id and this field is nullable for users that arent students. The parent_id field is the id of another user in the same table

**What i want to achieve**

I want to be able to return an eloquent relation with the parent of a child based on the parent_id of the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be that tricky. The relationship will returns one instance of model, which is the parent. Just play around with your table name, foreign key and so on.

```
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Similarly, you can quite do the same thing in reverse: get all "child student" of the current model instnace:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'parent_id');
}
```